# Add border to frameless window - Electron

Tags: javascript, html, css, electron

How can I properly add border to a [frameless](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/frameless-window.md) electron browser window?
My frameless window height is according to the content in the page which makes it difficult to add border around it.

This is how i'm doing it now:

1) I'm adding the border to html:

```
html{
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: slategray;
    border-width: 5px;
}
```

2) calculating the height of the window from the renderer side js:

```
let pageHeight = ( $('body').outerHeight(true));
    $('html').height(Math.ceil(pageHeight));
    let margin = 9;
    let electronWindowHt = Math.ceil(pageHeight)+margin;
    ipcRenderer.send('dom-ready-command',electronWindowHt);
```

3) setting the size of the window from the main js:

```
ipc.on('dom-ready-command', (event, height) => {
    clipboardWindow.setSize(config.WIDTH, height, false);
clipboardWindow.setPosition(clipwin_x, clipwin_y, false);
// other code
.
.
.
    })
```

The issue is it is **not pixel perfect**. Sometimes it works fine but sometimes when html body content increases or decreases I get a bit smaller height electron window than the content. which hides the bottom border and I need to scroll up to see that border. If I increase the height a bit then next time I get some white space left below the bottom border. Width is not an issue as it is always fixed.

As you can see in the below image, bottom border is hidden a bit because of smaller electron window size as compared to the content of HTML body.
[image]

So how can I make it pixel perfect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My *stoned* cousin put   `clipboardWindow.setSize(config.WIDTH, Math.ceil(height), false);` at the last line of `ipc.on('dom-ready-command')` event.

Strangely enough, it fixed the issue with the incorrect height. Now it's pixel perfect

Answer (score 1):

I know this has been answered but putting `box-sizing: border-box;` in your CSS should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I use Angular 10 for displaying frameless windows. The only way for me to determine window size int the renderer process was to use electronService this way:

`this._electronService['_electron'].webFrame.context`

Electron service was injected this way:
`constructor(private _electronService: ElectronService)`

And the module is `ngx-electron`.

Hope this will save some hours for somebody :)

Answer (score 0):

add css to body to fix(=add border to framelesswindow)

```css
border:1px soild lightgrey;
overflow:hidden;
box-sizing:border-box;
```

I test it is ok

Comment: It is helpful to explain why this CSS works to fix the issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).